# Sending Mail with Attachment

Tags: vb.net, email

I am trying to send an attachment with my email however it will not seem to work. I can send email when I do not try and use the attachment section

I am using these imports

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System
Imports System.Web.Mail

Dim mail As New MailMessage()
mail.To = strTo
mail.From = strFrom 
mail.Subject = strSubject
mail.BodyFormat = MailFormat.Html
mail.Body = sBody
'mail.Attachment.Add (strAttachment)
'mail.AddAttachment(strAttachment)


'mail.Attachments.Add(New MailAttachment(strAttachment))
 mail.Fields.Add("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate", "1") 'basic authentication
 mail.Fields.Add("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername", "xxxxxxxxxxxx") 'set your username here
 mail.Fields.Add("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword", "xxxxxxxxxxx") 'set your password here
 SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "xxxxxxxxxxxx" 'your real server goes here
 SmtpMail.Send(mail)
```

Comment: I have it commented out but those are the things I have tried and none of them are working.

Comment: strAttachment the variable that contains the path to the attachment

Comment: There is no error but there is no email being sent.

Comment: What isn't working?  Not being able to attach a file or just sending an email?  Your post and your comments are not being very clear.

Comment: @Steven: Is there an error on the SMTP server?  If you need to debug that side of things (which is immensely useful), take a look at smtp4dev: http://smtp4dev.codeplex.com

Comment: the email will send just fine if I remove the attachment section With the attachment section it will either cause an application error or with simply not send the email message at all.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
Dim m as new MailMessage
m.Attachments.Add(New Attachment("C:\Test.txt"))
'rest of your code
```

Comment: no this didn;t work An application error occurred on the server.

Comment: try using `System.Net.Mail` instead of `System.Web.Mail`. I use this code in production and it works fine

Comment: I have to use System.Web.Mail because of the host.